# Is it possible to simplify the below summation?

Tags: sum

I was doing some calculations, but cannot proceed further without some simplification to the below summation, is it possible to simplify it, so that it doesn't involve a summation?

$\sum_{x=0}^{s}\frac{(n-1)^{s-x}s!x}{n^sx!(s-x)!}$

Comment: What is the range of summation?

Comment: range of x values: 0 to infinity

Comment: You're sure it's not $0$ to $s$?  That would simplify things considerably...

Comment: What is $(s-x)!$ when $x$ exceeds $s$?

Comment: my mistake!, yes the maximum value of x is s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us fix the range of summation to be from $0$ to $s$.  Rearranging terms, we have:

$$\sum_{x=0}^s x {s \choose x}\left({n-1 \over n}\right)^{s-x}\left({1 \over n}\right)^x$$

which is the formula for the expectation of a Binomial variate with probability parameter $p = 1/n$ and count parameter $s$.  This expectation equals $s/n$.